# how to use pivot function when the index value has duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I am having following data frame

| INCIDENT | DATE | TITLE | ABS/FORECAST | DIRECTORY 098 | DIRECTORY 076 | DIRECTORY 027 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity 1 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | nAn | 2389 | 2842 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | forecasted | 2876 | 9200 | 6674 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | nAn | 8356 | nAn |
| entity 1 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | 1190 | 4544 | 7110 |
| entity 2 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | 9182 | 8128 | 2726 |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | forecasted | nAn | 6373 | nAn |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | absolute | nAn | nAn | 7737 |

which is converted into long using melt

```
  `df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["INCIDENT", "TITLE", "ABS/FORECAST", "DATE"], 
              var_name="KPI", value_name="Value")`
```

which looks like this

| INCIDENT | DATE | TITLE | ABS/FORECAST | KPI | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity 1 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 098 | nAn |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 098 | 2876 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 098 | nAn |
| entity 1 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 098 | 1190 |
| entity 2 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 098 | 9182 |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 098 | nAn |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 098 | nAn |
| entity 1 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 076 | 2389 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 076 | 9200 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 076 | 8356 |
| entity 1 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 076 | 4544 |
| entity 2 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 076 | 8128 |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 076 | 6373 |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 076 | nAn |
| entity 1 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 027 | 2842 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 027 | 6674 |
| entity 2 | 26/4 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 027 | nAn |
| entity 1 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 027 | 7110 |
| entity 2 | 26/5 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 027 | 2726 |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | forecasted | DIRECTORY 027 | nAn |
| entity 3 | 26/6 | prior | absolute | DIRECTORY 027 | 7737 |

now this needs to h=get converted into wide format where the directory has single unique row entry.
I tried to use PIVOT FUNCTION, but due to the duplicity it throws error as: 'Incident' is not in list

```
df3= df2.pivot(index='KPI',columns=["Incident", "DATE", "ABS/FORECAST"], values= 'Value')
```

Comment: pivot1=pd.pivot_table(df,index='KPI',columns=['Incident',TITLE','Segment','ABS/FORECAST','Date',],values='value')
pivot1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.melt(['INCIDENT','DATE', 'TITLE'], var_name = 'DIRECTORY LIST')

   INCIDENT  DATE  TITLE DIRECTORY LIST value
0  entity 1  26/4  prior  DIRECTORY 098   nAn
1  entity 2  26/5  prior  DIRECTORY 098  9182
2  entity 3  26/6  prior  DIRECTORY 098   nAn
3  entity 1  26/4  prior  DIRECTORY 076  2389
4  entity 2  26/5  prior  DIRECTORY 076  8128
5  entity 3  26/6  prior  DIRECTORY 076  6373
6  entity 1  26/4  prior  DIRECTORY 027  2842
7  entity 2  26/5  prior  DIRECTORY 027  2726
8  entity 3  26/6  prior  DIRECTORY 027   nAn
```

Comment: Aleary converted using melt but i need in Wide format with directory  as single row entry which can be done using pivot but its throwing error

Comment: @ASSOND this question has been marked as duplicate. Only this solution is feasible. No other solution can be added. So no need of edditing your post. If you have a question, you better ask it on another new question